# How to connect a "azurerm_windows_web_app" resource in Terrafrom with a Virtual Network

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-virtual-network

I am using the "azurerm_windows_web_app" resource type in terraform to create an app service. I am using this resource because the "azurerm_app_service" is being deprecated as indicated by the docs.

I need to setup the outbound traffic section of the app service to use a virtual network like below. I already have the virtual network being created successfully, so I just need to find a way to link it to the app service via terraform.

[image]

I cannot see any property on the resource that allows me to achieve this. On the "azurerm_app_service" resource I can see a "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" which I think might achieve this, but I cannot see a corresponding resource for a "azurerm_windows_web_app" resource to connect it to a virtual network.

Does anybody know if there is currently a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

`app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection` should still be the right one. The app services resources have been split up with the latest 3.0 TF provider release but I believe the swift resource will cover both, Windows and Linux app services.

Comment: I gave that resource a go but kept getting errors in my terraform Apply with no real error message other than getting a "409". I assumed this was because I was trying to use "app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" and assigning the "app_service_id" property to be the id of my "azurerm_windows_web_app", but the reason could well be something else in this case. I will persit with that resource and see if I can track down what the error is.